# Find all missing subsets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with columns representing different enemies in a game, and rows representing levels.

I want to make sure I've covered every combination (subset) of different enemies across my whole game.

How can I get Excel to tell me those subsets that I haven't covered yet? My table looks like:

```
    A B C
1   Y Y
2   Y   Y
3     Y
```

e.g. Level 1 Contains enemy A and enemy B.

In the above example, I don't have levels with the following subsets of enemies:

- A
- C
- B,C
- A,B,C

How could I get excel to produce that list for me? I can use macros if necessary, but would prefer not. In my actual excel spreadsheet, I currently have around 20 enemies.

Comment: So you want to find all the subsets of a set of 20 items. If you subtract the empty set, there are 1048575 such subsets, which is coincidentally (after including a header) the number of rows in a spreadsheet. Are you sure you want to do this in Excel?

Comment: Interesting, what's the algorithm for getting that number?

Comment: `2^n`. https://www.math-only-math.com/subsets-of-a-given-set.html

Comment: hmm ok, that might be too many levels then!! Still, knowing how to get Excel to do it would be useful